# excel lookup the maximum time that is less than a given time for a given login

Tags: excel, lookup

```
login   data    time                    2:02:05PM
F   0.705280578   2:01:54 PM        A   
F   0.43345391    2:01:57 PM        B   
B   0.808904475   2:02:00 PM        C   
D   0.850244432   2:02:02 PM        D   
A   0.22279737    2:02:04 PM        E   
A   0.292236263   2:02:03 PM        F   
C   0.570515322   2:02:14 PM            
D   0.628746705   2:02:15 PM            
E   0.786526527   2:02:15 PM            
C   0.448511746   2:02:18 PM            
B   0.67269431    2:02:19 PM            
E   0.315507414   2:02:22 PM
```

I'm looking for the maximum time that is less than 2:02:05PM for each alphabet. so I need the formula to give me 2:02:04PM for A because that's the maximum value for A that's less than 2:02:05PM. see image to clearly understand the question. The formula would go into F2:F7.

[image]

Comment: The newer [MAXIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) xl2016/365 function would make short work of this problem.

Comment: yes, unfortunately for me I dont have that. :(

Comment: That's what I figured; my comment was targeted toward future viewers with a similar issue that might. Glad you got sorted out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure the value in F1 is *actually a time* and not just *text that looks like time*.  In your provided sample data and in your screenshot, the value in F1 is text that looks like time.  Put a space between the time value and the PM to correct that.

Then, in cell F2 use this formula and copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,$E2,$C$2:$C$13,"<"&$F$1)=0,"N/A",MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$13=$E2)*($C$2:$C$13<$F$1)*$C$2:$C$13,)))
```

[image]

Of course, adjust the ranges to suit your actual data.

Comment: I had a couple of formatting issues in my file. you're formula worked. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If "login" is in `A1`, enter this into `F2` and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$13=E2)*($C$2:$C$13<$F$1)*$C$2:$C$13,))),"No login before "&TEXT($F$1,"h:mm:ss AM/PM"))
```

Comment: formula returned: No login before 2:02:05 PM for all cells

Comment: @SamuelTaye It looks like your time in `F1` is entered as text instead of a time. Try adding a space so that it is "2:02:05 PM" instead of "2:02:05PM". This should correct the problem you had with tigeravatar's solution as well. Both solutions work for me.

Comment: I changed the format from text to time and also inserted a space. I'm still stuck because it's returning N/A.  you said you tried both formulas and it worked fine. can I see it? is it possible to attach your file?